# In SQL how do I create a running total based on a field that starts out as ""?

Tags: sql, procedure, cumulative-sum

I'm an sql novice and am working on a procedure where I'm trying to capture a running total based on three fields that a user inputs, Deduction PayCodeCat & EmployeeID, however if the employee is not in the table yet the running total column starts out as null.

The simplified procedure:

> ALTER  PROCEDURE  [dbo].[2023_ClaimsInsert]
> (
>
> @PayCodeCat               NVARCHAR(3)
> ,
> @EmployeeID           INT
> ,
> @Deduction            FLOAT
> )
>
> AS
> BEGIN
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>
> insert .dbo.[2023_ClaimsTable]
> (
> PayCodeCat
> ,
> EmployeeID
> ,
> Deduction
> ,
> QW_RunningBalance
> ,
> AS_RunningBalance
> ,
> ZX_RunningBalance
> )
>
> values
> (@PayCodeCat
> ,
> @EmployeeID
> ,
> @Deduction
> ,
> (SELECT sum(Deduction)+@Deduction FROM 2023_ClaimsTable CL WHERE @PayCodeCat = 'QW'
> AND  @EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID)
> ,
> (SELECT SUM(Deduction)+@Deduction FROM 2023_ClaimsTable CL WHERE @PayCodeCat = 'AS'
> AND  @EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID)
> ,
> (SELECT SUM(Deduction)+@Deduction FROM 2023_ClaimsTable CL WHERE @PayCodeCat = 'ZX'
> AND @EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID)

These are the results, anytime the Employee is new to the table the running balance starts at Null.

| EmployeeID | PayCodeCat | Deduction | QW_RunningBalance | AS_RunningBalance | ZX_RunningBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | AS | 100 |  | **Null** |  |
| 1 | AS | 200 |  | 300 |  |
| 1 | AS | 800 |  | 1100 |  |
| **2** | AS | 700 |  | **Null** |  |
| 2 | AS | 200 |  | 900 |  |
| 1 | QW | 200 | 200 | 1100 |  |

I tried modifying the value statements to include OR IS Null

- (SELECT sum(Deduction)+@Deduction FROM AP_2023_ClaimsTable CL WHERE @PayCodeCat = 'AP' AND (@EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID **OR CL.EmployeeID IS NULL**))

Based on what I found on other stackoverflow answers I tried using Exists and Not exists, and case statements but I just broke the code.

Comment: Hello, I'm still trying to solve this one. I tried this case statement but while it solves the issue above it creates multiple records (one for each employee) where I'm only looking for one records for the specified employee.          
                                                  
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, CASE WHEN *PayCodeCat = 'AP' AND  *EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID THEN SUM(Deduction)+ *Deduction
--             WHEN *PayCodeCat = 'AP' AND  EmployeeID = NULL THEN *Deduction
-- END 
-- FROM AP_2023_ClaimsTable CL

*forced to remove at symbols

Comment: Similar results with this IIF statement. 
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, IIF(*PayCodeCat = 'AP' AND *EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID,(IIF(@EmployeeID = CL.EmployeeID,SUM(Deduction)+ *Deduction, *Deduction)), NULL) FROM AP_2023_ClaimsTable CL
 GROUP BY EmployeeID

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below Query to get the results,

```
SELECT EmployeeID, PayCodeCat, Deduction,
        CASE WHEN PayCodeCat = 'AS' THEN SUM(Deduction) over (Partition by EmployeeID, PayCodeCat Order by rn) END AS AS_RunningBalance,
        CASE WHEN PayCodeCat = 'QW' THEN SUM(Deduction) over (Partition by EmployeeID, PayCodeCat Order by rn) END AS QW_RunningBalance,
        CASE WHEN PayCodeCat = 'ZX' THEN SUM(Deduction) over (Partition by EmployeeID, PayCodeCat Order by rn) END AS ZX_RunningBalance
FROM (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EmployeeID, PayCodeCat) as rn
    FROM 2023_ClaimsTable
) a
```

Comment: Hi milindgv94, I tried adding your query to the procedure, but when adding the  @Deduction to each case statement I received the below error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Updated case statement: 
CASE WHEN PayCodeCat = 'AS' THEN (SUM(Deduction)+@Deduction) over (Partition by EmployeeID, PayCodeCat Order by rn) END AS AS_RunningBalance,
---- Error message ---- 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: Hi, please do not use variable, (SUM(Deduction)+@Deduction) instead just use SUM(Deduction).

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as it returns a table where I need to have it return one value. I need it to return the sum of Deductions in the 2023_ClaimsTable with an EmployeeID = '@EmployeeID' & PayCodeCat = '@PayCodeCat' match PLUS a new entry captured in the variable '@Deductions'. The new entry would include a RunningBalance for the matching PayCodeCat. I can get the RunningBalance's to work when an EmployeeID already exists in the 2023_ClaimsTable, however it returns null when the EmployeeID does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to apply the `@Deduction` only to the `XX_RunningBalance` that matches the `@PayCodeCat`, I think your code would look better like this:

```
ALTER Procedure [2023_ClaimsInsert] (
      @PayCodeCat   nvarchar(3)
    , @EmployeeID   int
    , @Deduction    float
    ) as
begin
    set nocount on
    insert into [2023_ClaimsTable] (
          PayCodeCat
        , EmployeeID
        , Deduction
        , QW_RunningBalance
        , AS_RunningBalance
        , ZX_RunningBalance
        )
    select
          @PayCodeCat
        , @EmployeeID
        , @Deduction
        , nullIf(
            (select isNull(SUM(Deduction), 0) from [2023 _ClaimsTable]
              where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID and PayCodeCat = 'QW' )
            + case @PayCodeCat when 'QW' then @Deduction else 0 end, 0)
        , nullIf(
            (select isNull(SUM(Deduction), 0) from [2023 _ClaimsTable]
              where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID and PayCodeCat = 'AS' )
            + case @PayCodeCat when 'AS' then @Deduction else 0 end, 0)
        , nullIf(
            (select isNull(SUM(Deduction), 0) from [2023 _ClaimsTable]
              where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID and PayCodeCat = 'ZX' )
            + case @PayCodeCat when 'ZX' then @Deduction else 0 end, 0)
end
```